# Flutter and FCM - Android Multiple Background Notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have written a Flutter app with Firebase Cloud Notifications and it works OK. But I am struggling to get it working with multiple background messages in the way I would like

Scenario:

- My app is in background and two messages arrive. These are visible in the Android notification area
- Tap on one message, onMessageOpenedApp will be called and I have written code to take the user in to the application's notification page which list the notifications arrived.
- Because I am adding messages to notification list in onMessageOpendApp, I cannot see the second message
- I am adding the notification to the list in the onMessageOpenedApp because I am using a Provider to update the notification list which needs a 'context'
- I feel I have to add the message to the notification within the handler defined for onBackgroundMessage but I cannot use 'context' if I do so.

I feel I have got this wrong. Can you please let me know what should be done?

I have shown the code snippets from my app below.

```
//Handler to handle backgrount FCM messages - As a first level method 
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
   print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
 }
 .
 .
 .
 //Register the background messaging handler
 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
 .
 .
 .
 
// For handling notification when the app is in background but not terminated
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Message received while background  ${message.notification.title}');
  //Add the new notification to the list
  PushNotification newBgNotification = PushNotification(
                                         body: message.notification.body,
                                        title: message.notification.title,
                                     imageURL: message.notification.android.imageUrl,
  );

  Provider.of<FCMService>(context, listen: false).addNewNotification(newBgNotification);
  print('-----------------Background Message aded to notification list');
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notifications');
});
```

Comment: Maybe add the details of the incoming message in a specific static list or save them via shared preferences as soon as they arrive, so you have all the details of the notifications even if there are more than 1.

Comment: @Darshan thought about using shared preferences but is it a good practice to use. The state seems to be scattered all around in that, For example, when I tap on the first message I can get the messages from the shared preferences and populate the notification list. What should I do when I tap on the second message. I have to check a messageId or something like that and if not already added, I have to add them.... feels like monkey patching ...

Comment: On the other hand SharedPrefs are for simple key:value pairs and message structure is hard to maintain in it

Comment: you serialize & deserialise objects & convert them to list as string & add then to shared preferences or try using sqflite.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, to handle background message from terminated state you should use `getInitialMessage()` method without `onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);`

`getInitialMessage()` returns `RemoteMessage` from corresponding notification, so you don't have to save multiple incoming `RemoteMessage` from `onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler)` to local storage

Comment: Thanks @TijaniRF. I'll check that out